# How to put a conditional new line when showing table data using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs v 1.4.x.

I have a scenario where in I need to show the time slots for user selection.
Only the available time slots need to be shown to the user.

I have created a plnkr for the same but I have not been able to get the desired result. I tried `ng-switch`, `ng-repeat-start` but to no success.

**HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-Controller="MainCtrl">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Total Slots {{slotAvailableForSelectionCount}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="slot in slotInfo.slots">
          <td ng-if="slot.isAvailable">{{slot.slotTime}}</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS File:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.slotInfo = {
    "slots":[
    {"sequence":1,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"9:00 AM"},
    {"sequence":2,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"9:15 AM"},
    {"sequence":3,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"9:30 AM"},
    {"sequence":4,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"9:45 AM"},
    {"sequence":5,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"10:00 AM"},
    {"sequence":6,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"10:15 AM"},
    {"sequence":7,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"10:30 AM"},
    {"sequence":8,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"10:45 AM"},
    {"sequence":9,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"11:00 AM"},
    {"sequence":10,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"11:15 AM"},
    {"sequence":11,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"11:30 AM"},
    {"sequence":12,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"11:45 AM"},
    {"sequence":13,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"12:00 PM"},
    {"sequence":14,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"12:15 PM"},
    {"sequence":15,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"12:30 PM"},
    {"sequence":16,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"12:45 PM"},
    {"sequence":17,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"1:00 PM"},
    {"sequence":18,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"1:15 PM"},
    {"sequence":19,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"1:30 PM"},
    {"sequence":20,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"1:45 PM"},
    {"sequence":21,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"2:00 PM"},
    {"sequence":22,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"2:15 PM"},
    {"sequence":23,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"2:30 PM"},
    {"sequence":24,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"2:45 PM"},
    {"sequence":25,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"3:00 PM"},
    {"sequence":26,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"3:15 PM"},
    {"sequence":27,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"3:30 PM"},
    {"sequence":28,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"3:45 PM"},
    {"sequence":29,"isAvailable":false,"slotTime":"4:00 PM"},
    {"sequence":30,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"4:15 PM"},
    {"sequence":31,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"4:30 PM"},
    {"sequence":32,"isAvailable":true,"slotTime":"4:45 PM"}]};

    $scope.slotAvailableForSelectionCount = 0;
    isAnySlotSelectionAvailable = function(){
                if($scope.slotInfo != null && $scope.slotInfo.slots != null){
                    for(var i=0; i<$scope.slotInfo.slots.length ;i++){
                        if($scope.slotInfo.slots[i].isAvailable == true){
                            $scope.slotAvailableForSelectionCount = $scope.slotAvailableForSelectionCount + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            isAnySlotSelectionAvailable();
});
```

**Desired result:**

> 1:15 PM   1:30 PM   3:00 PM   3:15 PM
>   
> 3:30 PM    3:45 PM   4:15 PM   4:30 PM
>   
> 4:45 PM

**Plunker:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/GywMB3Ul98rsPRhxV6C4?p=preview

The time to be shown is determined by the property `isAvailable = true`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It works this way with me on the link given? I get exactly these values as desired result?

Comment: In the plunker I have given, all times are shown in one column. I want it divided in 4 columns and then to the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes:

in js remap your day into sections:

```
$scope.hours = [];
$scope.slotInfo.slots.forEach(function(v, k) {
    if (v.isAvailable) {
        var ary = v.slotTime.split(':');
        $scope.hours[ary[0]] = $scope.hours[ary[0]] || [];
        $scope.hours[ary[0]].push(v);
    }
});
```

It basically creates an array of hours where there are available slots.
In each hour element will be an inner array of slots that are actually vailable.

in your html, create two ng-repeats:

```
<tr ng-repeat="hour in hours track by $index">
    <td ng-repeat="slot in hour">{{slot.slotTime}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here's the updated plunker that works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XiWYgv2AQnroLtY5qTZC?p=preview

UPDATE:

Based on what OP's updated requirement, I've updated the plunker above to produce the result.

Simply change the code in app.js to this:

```
$scope.hours = [];
var slots = [];
$scope.slotInfo.slots.forEach(function(v, k) {
    if (v.isAvailable) {
        if (slots.length === 4) {
            $scope.hours.push(slots);
            slots = [];
        }
        slots.push(v);
    }
});
// don't forget to push the final slots
$scope.hours.push(slots);
```

Comment: Thanks Will. Your answer is close but I do not want any empty slot if there is a next slot available. Sorry, that it is not clear from my question.

Comment: Then what do you want to be displayed in that empty space instead?

Comment: I have updated my question with the desired layout and updated the plunker link as well. All time slots should be show consecutively until 4 columns are filled up or there are no more slots available.

Comment: Thanks very much Will. You rock :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the plunkr (as per comments from Will and you) and I hope it is near to what you are expecting. Do you have any specific requirement to use `table` or any other HTML element is fine

```
<p class="title">Total Slots: {{slotAvailableForSelectionCount}}</p>
<div class="container" ng-repeat="slot in slotInfo.slots">
  <div class="slot" ng-if="slot.isAvailable">{{slot.slotTime}}</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is correct

http://plnkr.co/edit/ResdNr904UKrrzgvsquY?p=preview

Comment: Not what OP wants.   He actually posted an image of what he wants.

Comment: yes and that is confusing since that is exactly what is there in plnkr example. I am trying to figure it out from the title

Comment: But your plunker didn't give the answer he wanted.

Comment: The layout I want is the one I mentioned in my question. The plunker I mentioned is what I tried but not able to get the desired layout.

Comment: do you always need to display 4 columns in a row or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Yes. I want to show 4 columns and I need to use the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't need a `<table>` this would be nearly trivial; just start a new row based on the ng-repeat `$index`. (This requires changing your `ng-if` to a filter on the `ng-repeat` -- otherwise `$index` would refer to the unfiltered data):

```
    <span ng-repeat="slot in slotInfo.slots | filter:{isAvailable:true}">
      {{slot.slotTime}}
      <div ng-if="$index % 4 == 3"><!-- new row --></div>
    </span>
```

There's no simple way to map that technique to a table's HTML structure, though.

If you need a `<table>` you'll probably want to chunk the array into rows inside your directive or controller:

```
var chunkArray = function(arr,n) {      
  // splits arr into a 2d array with n items per row
  var ret = [];
  while(arr.length > 0) {
    ret.push(arr.splice(0,n));
  }
  return ret;         
}

// filter out the items which aren't isAvailable, and 
// chunk the rest into rows of 4 each:
$scope.availableSlots = chunkArray(
  $filter('filter')($scope.slotInfo.slots, {isAvailable: true})
  , 4
);
```

before passing it to the template:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in availableSlots">
    <td ng-repeat="col in row">{{col.slotTime}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

...as seen in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hn1tYXl9YUgL5VUYO4dM?p=preview).